# HTML Buttons Aren't Deselecting After Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making a calculator app for class and I have run into a snag while implementing keyboard listeners. Everything on the keyboard side works properly, but I have found that when I am forced to physically click on a button, such as the more obscure functions which don't have keyboard keys, the button is staying focused. This normally wouldn't be an issue, except that every time I press the 'enter' key to solve the inputted function, the calculator thinks I'm pressing that focused button.

CSS hasn't worked and I can't find anything on Google for how to deactivate this. If it matters, I am using Bootstrap 3 for this. We haven't covered JQuery yet, so I'm hoping for a pure JS way to solve this if it's possible.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle or codepen? or any code snippets?

Comment: Have you tried giving focus to the Window object after each keypress/mouseclick?

Comment: @andrew I do not have a jsfiddle. It's all in my [github](https://github.com/rrapstine/codeup.dev/tree/master/public/calculator) though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for the responses. I tried both and my issue was solved, however it took either an extra function or an extra listener. I ended up finding the [blur()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur) function and calling it at the end of my switch statement which controls clicks accomplished what I wanted. Thank you again though!

Answer (score 0):

After each mouse click, change the focus back to the equals or solve button, using the [focus() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus). That way when the user does eventually press enter, your code will think they're clicking the solve button

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event handler like bind -> keypress just for Enter key.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).bind('keypress',pressed);
});

function pressed(e){
     if(e.keyCode === 13){
          //Call your result function here
     }
}
```